# How does ibm - mobile first get mobile number from security context?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am following "isRegistered" api from [this](https://github.com/mfpdev/sms-one-time-password-sample/blob/master/sms-otp/src/main/java/com/github/mfpdev/sample/smsOTP/SMSOTPResource.java) sample code. I did not understand how we get phone number from security context.

The API that I want to use is:

```
@Path("/isRegistered")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@OAuthSecurity(enabled = true)
@ApiOperation(value = "Check if a phone number is registered",
        notes = "Check if a phone number is registered",
        httpMethod = "GET",
        response = Boolean.class
)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK",
                response = String.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Not Authorized",
                response = String.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Cannot check if phone number is registered",
                response = String.class)
})

public Boolean isRegistered() {
    //Getting client data from the security context
    ClientData clientData = securityContext.getClientRegistrationData();
    if (clientData == null) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException("This check allowed only from a mobile device.");
    }

    String number = clientData.getProtectedAttributes().get(SMSOTPSecurityCheck.PHONE_NUMBER);
    return number != null && !number.trim().equals("");
}
```

How does the security context have the client phone number?

Comment: Please include code in the question body

Answer (score 0):

There is a client project as well in this sample. Please refer to the complete sample.

Within the client side logic [here](https://github.com/mfpdev/sms-one-time-password-sample/blob/master/sms-otp-sample/SMS/MainViewController.swift), the user is asked to provide the phone number , which is sent to the server in an adapter call:

```
MainViewController.codeDialog("Phone Number", message: "Please provide your phone number",isCode: true) { (phone, ok) -> Void in
 if ok {
         let resourseRequest = WLResourceRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"/adapters/smsOtp/phone/register/\(phone)")!, method:"POST")
.....
```

Now in the adapter [code](https://github.com/mfpdev/sms-one-time-password-sample/blob/master/sms-otp/src/main/java/com/github/mfpdev/sample/smsOTP/SMSOTPResource.java) path @Path("/register/{phoneNumber}") notice the following code:

```
clientData.getProtectedAttributes().put(SMSOTPSecurityCheck.PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
    securityContext.storeClientRegistrationData(clientData);
```

This is how the phone number made it to the security context.

Run the sample and use a tool such as Wireshark to analyze the data flow between client and server.

Comment: I want to register a mobile number only if it is not registered. So, to check if it is registered, I want to call "isRegistered" api first. So how does "isRegistered" api get the mobile number? For example, my apk file is installed in two mobile devices. One mobile number is registered with the server and the other is not. How does the server differentiate between the two devices when I am not sending the mobile number? How does it know where it got the call from?

Comment: Since the complete project is available to you , I suggest you try it out first before asking all the questions. Wireshark is an excellent tool that will show you what parameters are reaching the server and what server responds with.